# How do I say that an infection was transmitted to me by droplet contact without sounding weird?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases, expressions, medical

There's a list of ways an infection can be transmitted from one person to another: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_(medicine)

I can say, "This infection was transmitted to me sexually". 
In the same way I wish I could say, "This infection was transmitted to me dropletly (or airbornely)", but obviously that's not proper English.

What is the proper way of saying this? Or is saying, "This infection was transmitted to me by airborne/droplet contact" good enough?

Comment: I hope you are not actually ill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say, "I was infected by an airborne disease."